# ArrayList logic for recent entries?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Basically, i have an `ArrayList` titled "recentContacts", and i have limited the number of entries to 10.

Now im trying to get the `ArrayList` to replace all the entries from the first index, **after** the list is full.

Here is some code to demonstrate...

```
            // Limits number of entries to 10
            if (recentContacts.size() < 10)
            {
                // Adds the model
                recentContacts.add(contactsModel);
            }
            else 
            {
                // Replaces model from the 1st index and then 2nd and 3rd etc...
                // Until the entries reach the limit of 10 again...
                // Repeats
            }
```

Note: The if statement above is just a simple example, and might not be the correct way to solve the problem.

What would be the most simplest way of achieving this?  Thanks!

Comment: Look into using [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), in particular look at `LinkedHashMap#removeEldestEntry()`.

Comment: Do you need someone doing that simple logic for you?

Comment: Simplicity is subjective. We are all on different skill levels. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to maintain the index of the next element that would be replaced.
Actually you can use that index even before the `ArrayList` is "full".

For example :

```
int index = 0; // initialize the index to 0 when the ArrayList is empty
...
recentContacts.add(index,contactsModel);
index = (index + 1) % 10; // once index reaches 9, it will go back to 0
...
```